# mvn dependency causing NoSuchMethod errors with htmlunit

Tags: java, maven, htmlunit

I have dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sourceforge.htmlunit</groupId>
    <artifactId>htmlunit</artifactId>
    <version>2.10</version>
</dependency>
```

And run a test that includes testing a website for form submission. Works great. I package this up into my local repo `mvn install` and include it in another wider project.

Doing a `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=net.sourceforge.htmlunit` doesn't seem to reveal anything untoward

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.8:tree (default-cli) @ myproject ---
[INFO] com.myproject:myproject:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] \- com.myproject:myproject:mp:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO]    \- net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit:jar:2.10:compile
[INFO]       \- net.sourceforge.htmlunit:htmlunit-core-js:jar:2.10:compile
```

So I don't think any of the other deps are causing an issue. Yet if I copy/paste a test from the base project into the wider one, I always get errors:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.getElementById(Ljava/lang/String;)Lcom/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/html/HtmlElement;
```

I've made sure my IDE isn't caching some dodgy library somewhere so as far as I can tell it's clean. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: do you have gwt artifacts `mvn dependency:tree -Dincludes="com.google.gwt:gwt-dev"` ?

Comment: No, but it is part of a Vaadin project which sits on top of gwt... Does gwt use HtmlUnit somewhere?

Comment: yes certainly it is shaded in some other jar, put this <dependency> of htmlunit at first entry of dependencies and retry that should fix it

Comment: Sweeeet! I did actually have the dep there, but was last not first. Thanks. Please post this as a solution and I'll give you a nice shiny medal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is you have this class coming from some other artifact, since you verified it is not directly coming from htmlunit with different version, it must be shaded in some other jar

for jvm to get pick up correct class please put htmlunit dependency on top of dependency so it will be first in classpath taking priority